# Can't export certificate from hosted Powershell session within C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm attempting to run a Powershell script to create and manipulate certificates from within a C# application. I'm using the library described in the Powershell Github repo at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/docs/host-powershell to give me access to a Powershell environment within which to run the script.

The script is as follows:

```
$derPath = "C:\Certs\derRootCert.cer";
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature -Subject "CN=P2SRootCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyUsage CertSign;
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -DnsName P2SChildCert -KeySpec Signature -Subject "CN=P2SChildCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Signer $cert -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2");
Export-Certificate -FilePath $derPath -Type CERT -NoClobber -Cert $cert;
```

If I run this script in a Powershell console myself, it works fine and I see the file output to the directory.

If I run it within the following C# however, I never see the file created:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
  ps.AddScript(stringContainingScript).Invoke();
}
```

Why isn't the file being written when run within this hosted context and what can I do to make it show up as expected?

Thanks!

EDIT:
At the advice of a comment, I looked at the error stream and found the following message:

> The term 'New-SelfSignedCertificate' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

So that begs a related question - why is a a non-elevated PowerShell window able to find that cmdlet, but my hosted console unable to?

Comment: Try running it as an administrator; your Powershell console might be running with elevated privileges. I think an access denied error would show up in your Powershell event logs

Comment: Inspect `ps.Streams.Error`

Comment: You're right - I looked into the error stream and found the following message: "The term 'New-SelfSignedCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

So that begs the next question - why is that available in a standard (non-administrative) prompt, but not available in a hosted context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I wound up going another route. When digging into why New-SelfSignedCertificate wasn't available, I tried explicitly adding "Import-Module pki" to the start of my script. That yielded another error:

> Module
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\pki\pki.psd1' does
>   not support current PowerShell edition 'Core'. Its supported editions
>   are 'Desktop'. Use 'Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck' to ignore the
>   compatibility of this module.

So, I modified my import to add that -SkipEditionCheck anyway to see what would happen. This time I got a lot of non-specific exceptions indicating that various modules failed to load.

I've gone in a different direction. Since my script doesn't write out anything to the console that I need and simply writes out my certificate to a directory, I've instead taken to writing the script out from my program to a temp file and launching Powershell as a process, passing the script location into the arguments and then doing some cleanup of the script before moving on with the rest of it, as in the following:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetTempFileName()) + ".ps1";
var tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
//Build the script
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile)) {
  sw.Write(sb.ToString());
}

var pi = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", $"-File {tempFile}") {
  CreateNoWindow = true,
  UseShellExecute = false
};
var p = Process.Start(pi);
p.WaitForExit();

var errorLevel = process.ExitCode; //If 0, the script ran without errors
p.Close()
File.Delete(tempFile);
```